# How to read or interpret the following null hypothesis?

Tags: quantile

I want to know how to read the following null hypothesis:

P{Fyt |Zt−1{Qθ (Yt−1)|Ζt−1} = θ} = 1

Comment: Assuming you're asking about _The Role of News-Based Uncertainty Indices in Predicting Oil Markets: a Hybrid Nonparametric Quantile Causality Method_, it is utterly off-topic for Stack Overflow. (Also, know that if you ask this anywhere else, the question is completely unanswerable without the context.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming at all.

Comment: ok....can you please suggest where can I ask this question? I want to read the mathematical notations in simple words. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possibly https://math.stackexchange.com, however, as @Amadan says you will have to provide a much better question with much more context.